# Am I using the conditional correctly?

Tags: condicional

I want to say :

> "Also, I am considering whether I should get a new or used one."

I figure I can say :

> "También, estoy considerando si debería obtener uno nuevo o vieja."

Is this correct? 
I use this app and it is telling me that I have to use imperfect subjunctive.

Comment: Just a minor question: why did you replace "used" for "viejo"? I guess it depends on the context, but just because something is used, it doesn't mean it's old. You can also say "uno nuevo o (uno) *usado*" or even "uno nuevo o (uno) *de segunda mano."*

Comment: I was thinking old.

Comment: @munchschair According to Yay's comment, if you intend to mean *old*, then *viejo* can be used but if you mean *usado* the word you need is *used.*

Comment: see [should in spanish](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/should) the last use matches yours.

Comment: @robertotomás That site is wrong; *should* does not imply *deber.*

Comment: @Ustanak — I think you misread the site. They aren't saying that deber imparts the meaning of "should", but that _deberia_ specifically does. What they are saying is in agreement with your own answer. I just provided a source.

Comment: @robertotomás I'm sorry, I meant this example: *I should go to bed early tonight to be ready to travel tomorrow morning = Debo acostarme temprano esta noche para estar listo para el viaje mañana*; *debo* does not stand for *debería*, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good, but one minor point: be always careful with gender agreement.

- *... obtener uno nuevo o viejo* or *... obtener una nueva o vieja.* (Context will decide whether you use the masculine or feminine gender.)

However, *debería* is not often used as a conditional, it's actually an *advice* or the right thing we believe we can do.

Comment: @Yay Al principio no me gustó tu edición pero después de leerla un par de veces se ve más estandarizado a lo que se dice usualmente cuando se introduce un consenso.

Comment: En efecto, yo siempre he visto "concordancia de género/número" traducido como "gender/number agreement". De todas formas, ya sabes que si no estás de acuerdo siempre puedes deshacer un edit :)

Comment: Haha, no te preocupes, está bien, la idea es dejarlo para que los nativos entiendan mejor.

Comment: Did I use deber correctly here?

Comment: @munchschair Yes, *should = debería.*